# C Inserting Struct into Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree

```
typedef struct word {
char *str;              /* Stores the word */
int freq;               /* Stores the frequency */
struct word *right;
struct word *left;
} Word;

Word *root = NULL;  //global variable

void * Insert(Word *node,Word *root)
        {
            //printf("inserted");
            if(root==NULL)
            {
                root = (Word *)malloc(sizeof(Word));
                root->str = (char*)malloc(strlen(node->str)+1);
                //printf("%s", node->str);
                strcpy(root->str,node->str);
                root->freq = node->freq;
                root->left = NULL;
                root->right = NULL;
            }
            else if (strcmp(node->str, root->str)==0){
                root -> freq = root->freq+1;
            }
            else if (strcmp(node->str, root->str)<1){
                Insert(node,root->left);
            }
            else {
                Insert(node,root->right);   
            }

            return 0;

        }
```

I'm trying iterate through a linked list of structs and insert them into a BST so I can output the strings in alphabetical order with an inorder traversal.  However, when i call my inorder, root is always null, so it doesn't iterate through.  I think my insert function may be wrong though.  I'm not really sure i need to be passing root through and operating on it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You have *one* return statement in this, and it returns 0 (i.e. NULL). Think about what your creating (and stop casting `malloc`), and where the resulting pointers from that creation need to be stored or `return`-ed. `root = ...` isn't going to change the *caller's* pointer. you need to return that change either by address (pointer-to-pointer) or by return value of your function. The choice is yours.

Comment: And a suggestion, review your notes carefully. If the purpose of this is indeed to build a frequency tree it is possible you don't have to copy the *string*. Rather, you can simply store the address already in whatever linked list node contains the original data. Doing so requires the source list nodes live as long as the tree your building, but it would significantly reduce the number of allocations (by-half), as the char pointers in your tree would be nothing more than pointers to the original (and only) copies of the source strings in your list.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm actually reading in a large text file, and splitting it up with threads.  The linked list is being reused by every thread.  That's why i copy the strings.  The purpose of building the BST was so that I could have all the strings stored in alphabetical order and output that at the end.  The threads will give their individual words and word counts.